# Converting Specific kind of String to Binary Tree

Tags: string, algorithm, binary-tree, parentheses

We have an input string in this format **`"(1(2(4)(5))(3(6(8)(9))(7)))"`** 
We have to build a Binary Tree such that `1` is the root node and the first complete bracket contains `(2(4)(5))` contains the family of `1`'s left child 
and `(3(6(8)(9))(7))` is the family of the right child of the root A.

 Finally the tree will look like this.

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBzuq.png)

I am not able to find the exact algorithm to write convert this one. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think Stack.
When you see a "(" push the element onto the stack, when you see a ")" pop the stack, but assign it as a child to the top element of the stack.

So lets go through the example `"( 1 ( 2 ( 4 ) ( 5 ) ) ( 3 ( 6 ( 8 ) ( 9 ) ) ( 7 ) ) )"`

- (1 -> push 1
- (2 -> push 2
- (4 -> push 4
- ) -> pop 4, but assign 4 as child to top of stack which is 2 ( see if left is available then assign as left child otherwise right child )

Current tree :

[image]

- (5 -> push 5
- ) -> pop 5, top of the stack is still 2 ( left is not available so assign it as right child of 2 )

Current tree:

[image]

- ) -> pop 2, top of the stack is 1 ( left of 1 is available, so assign 2 as left child of 1)

Current tree:

[image]

- (3 -> push 3
- (6 -> push 6
- (8 -> push 8
- ) -> pop 8, top of the stack 6's left is available assign 8 as left of 6

Current tree:

[image]

- (9 -> push 9
- ) -> pop 9 -> add it to top of stack's right child i.e. 6's right child because 6's left is taken as 8.

Current tree:

[image]

- ) -> pop 6 -> add it to top of stack i.e. 3's left child as it is available.

Current tree:

[image]

- (7 -> push 7
- ) -> pop 7 -> add it to top of stack i.e. 3's right child because 3's left child is taken as 6.

[image]

- ) -> pop 3 -> add it to top of stack i.e. 1's right child because 1's left child is taken as 2.

Current tree:

[image]

- ) -> pop 1 -> there is nothing in the stack now. Done.

Complete runnable example in Java with implementation using a stack is:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TreeNode root = buildTree("(1(2(4)(5))(3(6(8)(9))(7)))");
        levelOrder(root);
    }
    
    static class TreeNode {
        int val;
        TreeNode left, right;
        public TreeNode(int val) {
            this.val = val;
        }
    }
    
    private static TreeNode buildTree(String s) {
        Deque<TreeNode> dq = new ArrayDeque<>();
        TreeNode rootNode = null;
        for ( int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++ ) {
            if ( s.charAt(i) == '(' ) {
                Integer current = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(s.charAt(i+1)));
                dq.push(new TreeNode(current));
            } else if ( s.charAt(i) == ')' ) {
                TreeNode node = dq.pop();
                if ( dq.isEmpty() ) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    
                    rootNode = dq.peek();
                    if (rootNode.left == null) {
                        rootNode.left = node;
                    } else {
                        rootNode.right = node;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return rootNode;
    }
    
    private static void levelOrder(TreeNode root) {
        Deque<TreeNode> dq = new ArrayDeque<>();
        dq.offer(root);
        while(!dq.isEmpty()) {
            int sz = dq.size();
            
            for ( int i = 0; i < sz; i++ ) {
                TreeNode node = dq.poll();
                System.out.print(node.val + " ");
                if ( node.left != null ) {
                    dq.offer(node.left);
                }
                if ( node.right != null ) {
                    dq.offer(node.right);
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, I can't just write the code for your assignment here :-) but I think it may help if you think on each symbol as an operation, for example

```
( = down
1 = add
( = down
2 = add
( = down 
4 = add
) = up (goes to level of 2)
( = down
5 = add
) = up (goes to level of 2)
) = up (goes to level of 1)
( = down
3 = add
( = down
6 = add
( = down
8 = add
) = up (goes to level of 6)
( = down
9 = add
) = up (goes to level of 6)
) = up (goes to level of 3)
( = down
7 = add
) = up (goes to level of 3)
) = up (goes to level of 1)
) = up (leaves)
```

If you think in terms of a recursive algorithm, you may think of "going down" as a recursive method call and "going up" as returning from the recursive method call (which happens automatically, then the method itself completes).

I strongly suggest you to try to solve the problem because it's really important to learn.

However, if you still can't find the solution, you may find some detailed explanation here on how to solve it. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/construct-binary-tree-string-bracket-representation/

Comment: Thanks, I think we need to implement that via stack and then construct the tree.
I just extracted the characters and performed a level-ordered construction, it didn't work.
Thanks for your valuable suggestions

Answer (score 0):

The string lists the nodes in preorder sequence. So a recursive solution would be a possible choice.

In JavaScript you'd write it as follows:

```js
class Node {
    constructor(value) {
        this.value = value;
        this.children = [];
    }
}

function createTree(str) {
    // Extract numbers and parentheses from input into an array
    let tokens = str.match(/\d+|./g);
    if (!tokens) return null;
    let i = 1; // skip first character, as it must be a "("
    
    function recur() {
        let node = new Node(tokens[i++]);
        while (tokens[i++] != ")") {
            node.children.push(recur());
        }
        return node;
    }
    
    return recur();
}

// Demo run
let str = "(1(2(4)(5))(3(6(8)(9))(7)))";
let tree = createTree(str);
// Output the tree in JSON format
console.log(JSON.stringify(tree, null, 2));
```

Note that this implementation does not perform any validation of the input. It is assumed that the input has a correct syntax.

The algorithm will accept encodings of non-binary trees, as this format may encode nodes that have any number of children.